# RavenDB index query: OfType<T>().LastOrDefault() is not supported

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I'm using RavenDB 2.5.2879 and I noticed an issue. Is that a bug?

When I use FirstOrDefault(), the query works well.

```
session.Query<QueryModel>("App/Entities").Where(x => x.Tag == "Clients").OfType<Client>().FirstOrDefault();
```

When I use LastOrDefault(), I'm getting an exception "Could not understand expression: .Where(x => (x.Tag == "Clients")).OfType().LastOrDefault()"

```
session.Query<QueryModel>("App/Entities").Where(x => x.Tag == "Clients").OfType<Client>().LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 5):

That's by design.  If `Last` and `LastOrDefault` were supported, Raven would have to iterate through a potentially large data set just to return a single item.

Instead, use `FirstOrDefault` and provide a descending sort order.

```
session.Query<QueryModel>("App/Entities")
       .Where(x => x.Tag == "Clients")
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.Something)
       .OfType<Client>()
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Consider also that without *some* sort order, even an ascending sort is somewhat meaningless.  If you need first or last, you should apply a sort order first.